# count the no of specific values occurences in a specific column sql

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, count

This is my database
[image]

I want to count the No of **PRESENT** occurences in **ATTENDANCE** column for a specific **STU_ID**.

So far, I have tried...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ATTENDANCE) FROM STUDENT WHERE STU_ID=40;
```

But its showing distinct values only but I want how many presents are there in the column for a particular student.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE STU_ID = 40 AND ATTENDANCE = 'PRESENT'

Answer (score 2):

By doing COUNT(DISTINCT ATTENDANCE), you are counting the distinct values in the STU_ID column. And how many are there, two? Just "PRESENT" and "NOT PRESENT"?

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS AttendanceCount 
FROM STUDENT 
WHERE STU_ID = 40 
AND ATTENDANCE = 'PRESENT'
```

Or if you want to see each student, do

```
SELECT STU_ID, COUNT(*) AS AttendanceCount 
FROM STUDENT 
WHERE ATTENDANCE = 'PRESENT'
GROUP BY STU_ID
```

Comment: How do I make a table from the above one where I can count all the students no days present stream wise?